# Is this true about Fermat Primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

Let every prime of the form $2^n+1$ be called "Fermat Prime" (I know that the real definition is by using $2^{2^{n}}+1$, but I will use the other one to get things easier). By definition, we have that $p$ will be a Fermat Prime if and only if it is prime and it is not of the form $qn+1$ for any prime $q$ such that $2<q<p$.

Then, by Dirichlet Theorem on arithmetic progressions, we have that, as $N \to \infty$, the number of primes of the form $qn+1$ lower than $N$ will tend to be the same than the one of primes of the form $qn+2$ and of the one of the primes of the form $qn+3$; and like this up to $qn+(q-1)$.

So, to know the number of Fermat Primes as $N \to \infty$, we have that:

1. Only the primes of the form $3n+2$ can be a Fermat Prime. Then, as $N \to \infty$, The number of FM will be lower than $\pi(N)\frac{1}{2}$.
2. Only the primes of the form $5n+2, 5n+3$ and $5n+4$ can be a Fermat Prime. Then, as $N \to \infty$, The number of FM will be lower than $\pi(N)\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}$.
3. ...

If we continue like this, we would get that:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\pi_{\text{FermatPrimes}}(N)=\lim_{N \to \infty} \pi(N)\prod_{p>2}\frac{p-2}{p-1}=K \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\pi(N)}{\log{(N)}}$$

Which clearly diverges.

Is this true?

Comment: In your notation, Euler proved that factors are of the form $2q n+1$ and Lucas that they are of the form $4 q n+1$.  These are incompatible with your "$qn+1$ for any prime $q$ such that $2<q<p$."

Comment: @Eric But let $p$ be a Fernat Prime. As $p-1=2^n$, the only factor than $p-1$ can have is 2. From here, you get to the conclusion that if a composite number has a divisor ($q$) greater than 2, that number plus 1 cannot be a Fermat Prime

Comment: @user3141592 : And how does this make either $2q$ or $4q$ prime, as you have stated?

Comment: You actually have made the vacuous statement that the only numbers that can be Fermat primes are Fermat numbers.  That is, yes, all Fermat primes are a power of $2$ plus $1$.  Of course, all Fermat numbers are a power of $2$ plus one, so you have not said very much.

Comment: Additionally, you are doing neither your argument nor your reader any favors by using nonstandard notation.

Comment: @Eric What I have stated is that if $qn$ is not a power of two, $qn+1$ cannot be a FP

Comment: Since I can't make head or tails of how that claim fits with what you've already written, let's start very simply:  Where do you declare $p$, what is it, and what constraints does it have?

Comment: Yes, if $qn$ is not a power of two, $qn+1$ isn't even a Fermat *number*.

Comment: If I understood your process correctly, it would also "show" that there are infinitely many Mersenne primes. After all, a prime $p$ is a Mersenne prime if and only $2$ is the only prime factor of $p+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation (or rather, your heuristic, since there are issues of convergence of the limiting process to deal with) only gives necessary conditions for primes to be Fermat primes, not sufficient conditions. Therefore the expression you derive is simply an upper bound, not an asymptotic formula.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but could you give any example of another condition that Fermat Primes should deal with?

Comment: Greg, there is nothing wrong with the sieve. A prime is $p$ is a Fermat prime if and only if $2$ is the only prime divisor of $p-1$ if and only if $p\not\equiv1\pmod q$ for any odd prime $q<p$. The explanation, as you implied, probably has something to do with the convergence of the various limiting processes here. For example, it takes time for the Dirichlet densities to average out, and early on there may larger deviations from the average and/or larger deviations from independence. Because those appear as factors here, a handful of factors smaller than the expected $(p-2)/(p-1)$...

Comment: (cont'd) may bring the density of Fermat primes to zero. I am too fluish to think straight. I will ask a colleague.

Comment: @Greg Thank you very much! I see your point, but I do not understand why are you saying that "it takes time for the Dirichlet densities to average out", as I am working with a limit tending to Infinity. Could you please tell me exactly where is the error in my question? Also, could you explain to me what do you mean with "Problem of convergence"?

Comment: @Jyrki Sorry, I did not want to mention Greg but you

Comment: @user3141592: The point was that the estimate of the factor $(p-2)/(p-1)$ is not exact, when you are only counting primes up to $N$. That factor is of the form $1-\big(1/(p-1)+ E(p,N)\big)$, where $E(p,N)$ is an error term that for a **fixed** prime $p$ tends to $0$ when $N\to\infty$. But the estimates of that error term (I'm too ignorant to say how large they can be for relevant size $p$ and $N$) may make that product a lot smaller.

Comment: Also, similar error terms appear when we look at the distributions of the primes w.r.t. several moduli $p_1,p_2,\ldots$. Your product formula assumes these are independent. Asymptotically they are, but at any finite point the non-independence introduces yet other error terms.

Comment: The convergence issue might be described as saying that at any finite point $N$ you have many primes (notably those relatively large in comparison to $N$) with respect to whom $N$ is not large enough for the asymptotics to have kicked in.

Comment: To drive the point home: If $p$ is comparable to $N$, the primes $<N$ cannot be equidistributed among the residue classes modulo $p$. This is because there are $p-1$ such residue classes, but only $\pi(N)\ll p$ primes.

Comment: @Jyrki Thank you, that's nice. But, for what you have salid, I understand that both the error term $E$ and the "Convergence issue" occurs when we set a finite value to $N$, but they both tend to dissappear when $N \to \infty$

Comment: I don't see why they would disappear. As $N$ grows you get more and more of those error terms. The "convergence issue" is, perhaps, just an umbrella phrase for all the difficulties you get from having to deal with an increasing number of error terms each going to zero individually, but new ones popping up constantly.

Comment: @Jyrki Sorry if I seem to insist a lot, but this time I do not really see your point. By Dirichlet's theorem, the error term regarding the primes of the form $pn+1$ will decrease as $N \to \infty$. For example, the number of primes of the form $3n+1$ will tend to be a half of the total. I see that if you apply that to $\pi(N)$ for a finite $N$, there will obviosly be an error term. But it will also tend to disappear as $N$ gets bigger. And this, applied here to 3, could be extended to any prime $p$

Comment: I told you. The error term coming from the prime $p=3$ does tend to $0$. When you double $N$, the error term coming from $p=3$ drops in size in some predictable fashion. But, when you double $N$ you get new error terms from all the primes $p\in[N,2N]$. That's a lot of primes with still large error terms. Your formula for $\pi_{FermatPrime}(2N)$ has a product over all those primes $<2N$, and therefore may have a large error term.

Comment: @Jyrki Setting a finite 2N, that is true. But, for $N \to \infty$, would't $N$ be big enought to solve the error term problem for every prime? I think that the main problem between my idea and yours is how big of an infinity are we talking about

Comment: For the error term $E(p,N)$ to be small, $N$ needs to be large in comparison to $p$. For the total error to be small $N$ needs to be large in comparison to all the primes $p$. That is impossible.

Comment: @Jyrki By "in comparison to all the primes $p$", do you mean $\pi(N)$? If so, $N-\pi(N)$ will be greater the greater $N$ is